# Filtering a csv in R: unused argument (.SDcols = variable)

Tags: r

I am working with `R version 3.2.1` on `OS X Yosemite (Version 10.10.4)`.

Read a CSV file using:

```
> train = read.csv("~/Downloads/train.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Then initialized a variable:

```
> cat_var <- names(train)[which(sapply(train, is.character))]
> cat_var <- c(cat_var, 'BedroomAbvGr', 'HalfBath', ' KitchenAbvGr','BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'MSSubClass')
```

Now I want to find the total null values in the `cat_var` columns, but getting the following error:

```
> colSums(sapply(train[,.SD, .SDcols=cat_var], is.na))
Error in `[.data.frame`(train, , .SD, .SDcols = cat_var) : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = cat_var)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the NULL values (assuming it is `NA`), then the `data.table` approach is to first convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table`.  This can be done with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(train)
```

From the OP's code, it is not clear whether the conversion to `data.table` happened or not.  For example

```
mtcars1 <- copy(mtcars)
mtcars1[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = 1:2]
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(mtcars1, , lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = 1:2) :
>   unused argument (.SDcols = 1:2)

returns the error because it is a `data.frame`, however

```
setDT(mtcars1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = 1:2]
#     mpg cyl
#1: 642.9 198
```

---

Regarding the specific problem, we can directly read the file using `fread` to a `data.table`

```
train <- fread("~/Downloads/train.csv")
cat_var <- names(train)[unlist(lapply(train, is.character))]
```

and find the number of NA elements in the columns mentioned in `.SDcols` using `sum` and `is.na`

```
train[, lapply(SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), .SDcols = cat_var]
```

Comment: I understood my mistake of data.frame vs data.table. But on using data.table I am getting the following error. `Some items of .SDcols are not column names (or are NA)`

Comment: @nish  Please check the elements of `cat_var` and see if that column names are in the 'train' or if there are some unusual column names in the train..  The code I showed should work and I am using `1.10.0` version